# Shadertoy GLSL: Seeking Assistance to Make Vertical Lines Visible with Condition V.x == 0.6 – Code Not Rendering as Expected, Need Guidance

Tags: glsl, webgl, shadertoy

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XffGW4

```c
void mainImage( out vec4 O, vec2 U )
{
   vec2 V = mod(U, 100.);
   O = vec4( V.x == 0.5);
   // O = vec4( V.x == 0.6);
}
```

this is the result:
[image]

change 0.5 to 0.6 the vertical line disapears, why?

[image]

V.x range from -0.5 to 0.5 or 0 to 100?

I have try change the 0.5 but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`U` (which is actually `fragCoord`([gl_FragCoord](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragCoord.xhtml))) is the current fragment position center, so it's `.5` for the left most pixel, `1.5` for the fragment next to it etc. so the range of `V.x` will be `.5 - 99.5` in increments of `1.`.

Comment: thank you for your time. I have one more question: Why change 0.5 to 0.6, and the white lines disappears?